# Continuous text around sidewaysfigure-command

Tags: rotating

I am using the rotating-package to rotate large figures including their captions. The fact that the sidewaysfigure-command shows the figure on a single page is perfectly okay, because the figures are so large that they fill a whole page anyway. Yet I would like to have the text continuously around the figure.

I have the following example in my mind:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
First paragraph of text which does not fill  a whole page and refers to the test figure. \\

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[h]
\centering
\caption{Test}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

Here a second paragraph of text begins.
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the second paragraph is shown on the third page. Again, the fact that the first paragraph and the figure are shown on the first and second page, respectively, is perfectly fine. But how can I bring the second paragraph on the first page without shifting the whole sidewaysfigure-command behind the second paragraph? The point is that the first paragraph refers to the figure and the second paragraph might be so long that it spans over several pages. Thus, the second paragraph should start on page 1 after the first paragraph, then the figure should be shown on page 2, and finally the second paragraph should continue on page 3.
Could someone help me with that? Thanks a lot in advance.

Best,
Tiljim

Comment: The strange beahviout you mentioned doesn't occur with the MWE you provided. I get both paragraphs on page 1 and the figure on page 2. Not sure if it will help here, but remove the `[h]` placement specifier in your actual code. If the problem persists, we'll need a true MWE reproducing the problem.

Comment: I just realised that for my problem to be present, the second paragraph must large enough such that it actually spans over several pages. But anyway, removing the [h] already helped! I simply never thought about that a "here"-specification might shift things actually away from "here" ;-). Thank you.